# Converted string to char, when i cout the char it is correct but when I use chdir with the char it does not work?

Tags: c++

I am working on a program that includes the ability to print the working directory and change directories. Originally I had the user typing 'cd' which would call the cd function and ask them which directory to change to. This worked fine however I wanted to be able to do something like "cd /Users" all in one line. I've managed to split the string and pass the split part to the character variable I'm using for chdir fine, but for some reason chdir is not actually changing the directory with this method.

```
`void exec_cd(std::string destination)
{
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    char *directory;
    directory = new char [BUFFER_SIZE]; //Allocated memory in order to cin to the pointer char
    strcpy(directory, destination.c_str()); //Copy destination string into char directory
    //std::cout << "Enter target directory: " << std::endl << ">";
    //std::cin >> directory;
    std::cout << "TEST: " << directory;
    chdir(directory);
    delete [] directory;
}`
```

I commented out the old lines I had in there, when those were there instead of strcpy it worked fine. This function is passed everything entered after cd, I know the strcpy is doing its job because the line with "TEST :" outputs whatever it is supposed to (e.g. I type cd /Users) and it will show that directory indeed holds '/Users' it just is not working with chdir for some reason. I have a pwd function that works fine as far as I know but I will post that here too.

```
    void exec_pwd()
{
    long size;
    char *buf; //buffer holder
    char *ptr; //where the current directory will be saved to


    size = pathconf(".", _PC_PATH_MAX); //Gets size of path and saves it to size var.


    if ((buf = (char *)malloc((size_t)size)) != NULL) //Set buff = size of char * allocated size, if not null then get wd
        ptr = getcwd(buf, (size_t)size);

    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You should set the value of `errno` to 0 prior to calling `chdir` then inspect the value returned by `chdir` then inspect the value of `errno`. Also your buffer manipulation is completely useless and may potentially cause a buffer overrun. You can do `chdir(destination.c_str());`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing `chdir(destination.c_str());`? Also you should absolutely be checking the return value of `chdir` (and any other system calls). It could be that you're passing a bad path and `errno` has all the information you need.

Comment: I had chdir(dest...) at first but it has the same issue so I broke it out so I could look at it better...also I am using /Users as my test dir and I know that path works

Comment: Perhaps it is reading the space between my cd and /Users, that could be it..good idea with the errno, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed there was white space in the target directory, added a trim function to remove spaces before and after and issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that converting OS errors to `error_code`s as soon as possible is helpful.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>


std::error_code change_directory(std::string const& str)
{
    std::error_code result;
    if(chdir(str.c_str()))
    {
        result = std::error_code(errno, std::system_category());
    }
    return result;
}

void throw_on_failure(std::error_code ec)
{
    if (ec) throw std::system_error(ec);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        throw_on_failure(change_directory(argv[1]));
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```